# Devexpress ChartControl to XtraReport

Tags: c#, charts, devexpress, report

I have 2 chartcontrols in a wizard.
Is it possible to copy this charts to a XtraReport without using a xrChart?
Chartcontrol 1 is a bar chart and chartcontrol 2 is a pie chart.
The data comes from a datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Go through documentation section - [Use Charts, Grids and Custom Controls](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument15039)

This will help you to know that how can you add chart control to the xtrareport with data binding..

[How to: Create a Report with a Chart Containing Series Bound to Data](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/CustomDocument4576.aspx)
[How to: Create a Report with a Chart Bound to Data Using Series Templates](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/CustomDocument4575.aspx)

Hope these help..